# I see less connections than minIdle value at my "SHOW PROCESSLIST" query

Tags: tomcat7

I see less connections than minIdle value at my "SHOW PROCESSLIST" query
i have tomcat-7.0.59 installed in my Red Hat 4.4.7-11. Here is my context.xml db pool configurations:

```
maxActive="100"
minIdle="10"
initialSize="20"
maxWait="30000"
testOnBorrow="true"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
logAbandoned="true"
validationInterval="30000"
```

When i check my DB with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` i see 9 sleeping process so shouldn't i have to see 10 connections via `minIdle="10"` ? Why tomcat is not filling the pool?